# Writing Javascript code having everything in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I came accross this earlier from the PhoneGap/cordova files I was looking through:

```
  var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bind();
    },
    bind: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.deviceready, false);
    },
    deviceready: function() {
        // This is an event handler function, which means the scope is the event.
        // So, we must explicitly called `app.report()` instead of `this.report()`.
        app.report('deviceready');
        app.handleLogin();
    },
  }
```

I was just wondering what the benefit is of doing this as opposed to standalone functions executed on body load? Also if I was going to run a function on "pagebeforeload" in jquery mobile, how would I integrate this into the above pattern? Such as:

```
    $( '#mainMenu' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow', function(event){
    alert('pagebeforeshow');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, namespacing.

In JavaScript, everything is global unless you explicitly make it not global. This means names of things can clash, or you can overwrite things that you didn't mean to.  It's a big problem in larger programs.

The pattern you show namespaces all your app's functionality into a single `app` "object".  So anything that overwrites `bind` in the global scope, won't effect the value of `app.bind`.  The namespace protects it.

A good rule of thumb is to pollute the global namespace as little as possible.  In this case, you make `app` global, and that's it.  All your code hangs off that one global value.  Neat and tidy.

---

As to how to integrate your example. I might do something like this:

```
  var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        app.bindEventHandlers();
        // other setup code called here...
    },
    bindEventHandlers: function() {
        $( '#mainMenu' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow', app.pageBeforeShow );
        // other event handlers bound here...
    },
    pageBeforeShow: function() {
        alert('pagebeforeshow');
    },

    // other event handler functions declared here...
    // or whatever other functions or data your app needs here...
  }

  // start your app when the document is ready
  $(document).ready(function() {
    app.initialize();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you worked with OOP languages, then you know definition of class. JS is not support class-keyword, so to create objects with methods it should use following code. Then you can just call app.initialize() . Also it could give you advanced features in architecture of your application.

to integrate you code in existing functionality you should prototype.

```
app.prototype = { nameOfFunctionHere: function() { alert('pagebeforeshow'); } }
```

And then just call

```
app.nameOfFunctionHere();
```

to execute your function